# change font of the label without changing the size

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uifont

hey i want to change the font of the label without changing the size as i have different sizes for the different devices
See code below:-

this code works but as i said i don't want to change the size

```
QuotesLabel.font = UIFont(name: "optima", size: CGFloat(30)
```

here is the code for different sizes for different devices

```
 if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height == 480 {
        // iPhone 4
        QuotesLabel.font = QuotesLabel.font.fontWithSize(30)
    } else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height == 568 {
        // IPhone 5
        QuotesLabel.font = QuotesLabel.font.fontWithSize(30)
    } else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 375 {
        // iPhone 6
       QuotesLabel.font = QuotesLabel.font.fontWithSize(35)
    } else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 414 {
        // iPhone 6+
        QuotesLabel.font = QuotesLabel.font.fontWithSize(40)

    }
```

Comment: If QuotesLabel is not a class, it should start with a lower case 'quotesLabel'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can assign its own font size this way:

```
QuotesLabel.font = UIFont(name: "optima", size: QuotesLabel.font.pointSize)
```

**UPDATE:**

You can create and use font array this way:

```
let fontArr = ["helvetica", "optima", "arial"]   //Change this array as per your need
let int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(fontArr.count)))
QuotesLabel.font = UIFont(name: fontArr[int], size: QuotesLabel.font.pointSize)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this and one more thing can we also make an array of font to show different/random font everytime a person taps a button.

Comment: just show me the sample of three fonts example helvetica,optima,arial rounded mt bold

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85170/discussion-between-motivation-gym5-and-dharmesh-kheni).

Answer (score 2):

Use this UIFont Extension:

```
extension UIFont{
  func fontWithName(name:String)->UIFont{
    return UIFont(name: name, size: self.pointSize)!
  }
```

Then use it like this:

```
QuotesLabel.font = QuotesLabel.font.fontWithName("Verdana"
```

**UPDATE** : Random Font from an array

Define an array of fonts you want:

```
let fonts = ["Verdana", "HoeflerText-Black", "Menlo-BoldItalic"]
```

This function will return random Font:

```
func getRandomFont()->UIFont{
    let int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(fonts.count)))
    let font = UIFont(name: fonts[int], size: 30)
    return font
  }
```

On button Tap action call random Funtion and change TextField Font:

```
 @IBAction func testTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    QuotesLabel.font = getRandomFont()
  }
```

Comment: for the size should i add the same you told me

Comment: yes it'll work since `getRandomFont()` returns UIFont